# Can anyone suggest me how can i create this type of grid using angular UI Grid?

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid, angular-ui-grid

I have some trouble creating this type of grid because 3rd column is repeatable?

[image: Grid Image]

Comment: Why **repeatable** is a problem for you in this case? Can you explain and possibly provide what you have done so far?

Comment: Hi LIn, 
The KeyMile Stone, Due Date, and Comments are repeatable in each row. But there header is on top and i need the to apply sort  functionality as well.

Comment: That doesn't explain why repeatable is a problem. This is a basic UI-Grid layout, so the header is always on top and UI-Grid does provide sort functionality based on the header field. What I don't understand is what trouble are you facing for creating the layout like this. Can you be more specific? And a jsFiddle or Plunker will help!

Comment: HI this what i am getting when i am using ng-repeat. But i want to create each sub row header on top.

http://plnkr.co/edit/v8g19YpHNARz8UKCIAup?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

I'd try grouping rows by Initiatives Owner, Must-Win In., etc. columns.

[Alternatively apparently this has been already fixed on github.](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid/issues/1464)

Comment: Thanks :)
i have created [pluk](http://plnkr.co/edit/v8g19YpHNARz8UKCIAup?p=preview) 
I am not aware of grouping can you please suggest